# Problemas con los ID para poder llamar contenedores

Tags: javascript, html5, id, javascript-metodo

soy nuevo en javascript y se me esta complicando con las buenas practicas y evitar que haya problemas en el futuro.
Estoy creando una pagina que tiene una clase "Juegos". Esta clase tiene 2 listado de array.
"Plataformas" y "Generos", la logica que implemento es que un juego puede estar en varias plataformas, y seria lo mismo con el genero. Pude crear los ABM y quedo todo bien.

El problema que siempre me pasa, comienza cuando quiero crear el listado dinamico. Necesitando llamar dichos contenedores y no tengo formas de identificarlos, si no es mas que con el ID. Quise usar Name pero me dicen que tambien estaria mal eso.

```js
function CargarListadoFila(lista) {
    let contenedorPrimario = document.getElementById("listado-fila");
    let fila = "";
    let listaIdPlataforma = [];
    let listaIdGenero = [];
    /* lo que hago en esta funcion fue primero lo principal crear los article que son las filas con el contenido.
    Lo que me causo inconveniente, fue como ingresar al array dentro del array.
    Busque formas y la que mejor se me soluciono, aunque es un poco tosca. Es la siguiente*/
    for (let i in lista) {
        fila = `<article class="mt-4">
        <div class="row pt-3 contenedor-fila">
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 contenedor-img-fila">
                <img class="img-fila-juego" src="./img/juegos/GTAPS1.jpg" alt="">
            </figure>
            <div class="row col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                    <h3 class="titulo-fila-juego">GTA: SAN ANDREAS</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                    <h5>Tamaño:</h5>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger bg-gradient mt-1 span-lista-juego">10GB</span>

                    
                    <h5>Plataforma:</h5>
                    <div id="${lista[i].id}">
                    </div>


                    <h5>Genero:</h5>
                    <div id="${lista[i].id}">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p class="lead descripcion-fila-juego">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim est eligendi quia expedita veniam accusamus inventore velit? Saepe magni, voluptatum minus praesentium eum deserunt atque.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>`
        contenedorPrimario.innerHTML += fila;
        listaIdPlataforma.push(lista[i].id);
        listaIdGenero.push(lista[i].id);
    }
    /* Creo el contenedor de la plataforma, que llevara el ID de Listas de Juegos.
    Para poder llevar el ID de un lado a otro use un ARRAY */
    /* Luego creo un for de Listas de juegos, obteniendo el ID del contenedor,
     que con ello puedo encontrarlo al contenedor de la plataforma de dicho juego */
    for (let i in lista) {

        let IDcontenedorPlat = listaIdPlataforma.find(x => x == lista[i].id);
        let IDcontenedorGen = listaIdGenero.find(x => x == lista[i].id);


        let contenedorPlataforma = document.getElementById(IDcontenedorPlat);
        let contenedorGenero = document.getElementById(IDcontenedorGen);

        /* ya al tener el contenedor padre, creo los hijos segun el sub-array que tiene en lista juego */
        for (let p in lista[i].plataformas) {
            let item = document.createElement("span");
            item.textContent = lista[i].plataformas[p];
            item.className = "m-1 span-lista-juego bg-gradient btn btn-warning rounded-2";
            contenedorPlataforma.appendChild(item);
        }
        /* El problema que todavia no puedo solucionar, seria evitar que se repitan los ID */
        for (let g in lista[i].generos) {
            let item = document.createElement("span");
            item.textContent = lista[i].generos[g];
            item.className = "m-1 span-lista-juego bg-gradient btn btn-danger rounded-2";
            contenedorGenero.appendChild(item);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al principio funcionaba todo perfecto, con el de plataformas, me traia bien las cosas.
Quise probar agregando el de generos, ya viendolo venir que se iban a estar chocando los datos.
y termino sucediendo.

Necesitaria algun consejo o como es que lo hacen ustedes, para poder resolverlo al problema

Lo unico que estoy usando es JAVASCRIPT PURO, junto con el LOCALSTORAGE, sin tocar todavia bases de datos. No tengo conocimientos de otros lenguajes para poder implementar

Comment: Procura reformular tu pregunta para no solicitar consejos o sugerencias. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Tu pregunta podría ser "¿cómo acceder a elementos sin usar id o name?", por dar un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El id es usado para especificar una id única para un elemento HTML, tu id no puede repetirse. Por lo tanto tu código está mal, pues estás asignandole el mismo valor a 2 elementos diferentes, podrías usar un prefijo para nombrar tus id's, así evitarías este problema.
Tu código quedaría algo así:

```js
function CargarListadoFila(lista) {
    let contenedorPrimario = document.getElementById("listado-fila");
    let fila = "";
    let listaIdPlataforma = [];
    let listaIdGenero = [];
    /* lo que hago en esta funcion fue primero lo principal crear los article que son las filas con el contenido.
    Lo que me causo inconveniente, fue como ingresar al array dentro del array.
    Busque formas y la que mejor se me soluciono, aunque es un poco tosca. Es la siguiente*/
    for (let i in lista) {
        fila = `<article class="mt-4">
        <div class="row pt-3 contenedor-fila">
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 contenedor-img-fila">
                <img class="img-fila-juego" src="./img/juegos/GTAPS1.jpg" alt="">
            </figure>
            <div class="row col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                    <h3 class="titulo-fila-juego">GTA: SAN ANDREAS</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                    <h5>Tamaño:</h5>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger bg-gradient mt-1 span-lista-juego">10GB</span>

                    
                    <h5>Plataforma:</h5>
                    <div id="plataforma-${lista[i].id}">
                    </div>


                    <h5>Genero:</h5>
                    <div id="genero-${lista[i].id}">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p class="lead descripcion-fila-juego">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim est eligendi quia expedita veniam accusamus inventore velit? Saepe magni, voluptatum minus praesentium eum deserunt atque.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>`
        contenedorPrimario.innerHTML += fila;
        listaIdPlataforma.push("plataforma-" + lista[i].id);
        listaIdGenero.push("genero-" + lista[i].id);
    }
    /* Creo el contenedor de la plataforma, que llevara el ID de Listas de Juegos.
    Para poder llevar el ID de un lado a otro use un ARRAY */
    /* Luego creo un for de Listas de juegos, obteniendo el ID del contenedor,
     que con ello puedo encontrarlo al contenedor de la plataforma de dicho juego */
    for (let i in lista) {

        let IDcontenedorPlat = listaIdPlataforma.find(x => x == "plataforma-" + lista[i].id);
        let IDcontenedorGen = listaIdGenero.find(x => x == "genero-" + lista[i].id);


        let contenedorPlataforma = document.getElementById(IDcontenedorPlat);
        let contenedorGenero = document.getElementById(IDcontenedorGen);

        /* ya al tener el contenedor padre, creo los hijos segun el sub-array que tiene en lista juego */
        for (let p in lista[i].plataformas) {
            let item = document.createElement("span");
            item.textContent = lista[i].plataformas[p];
            item.className = "m-1 span-lista-juego bg-gradient btn btn-warning rounded-2";
            contenedorPlataforma.appendChild(item);
        }
        /* El problema que todavia no puedo solucionar, seria evitar que se repitan los ID */
        for (let g in lista[i].generos) {
            let item = document.createElement("span");
            item.textContent = lista[i].generos[g];
            item.className = "m-1 span-lista-juego bg-gradient btn btn-danger rounded-2";
            contenedorGenero.appendChild(item);
        }
    }
}
```